# Create a table as a result from 2 tables

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a table as a result of 2 tables Prices and Sales
The table should consist of 4 columns product/date/amount/revenue
where the first 3 columns are the total copy of Sales tables and the revenue column should be = sales.amount * prices.price

I get an empty table as a result

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE revenue(product VARCHAR(1), date DATE, amount FLOAT, revenue FLOAT);")
cursor.execute("INSERT into revenue SELECT sales.product, sales.date, sales.amount, prices.price*sales.amount FROM sales, prices")
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Hello @VladimirDemo, welcome to stack Owerflow. Can you show us two rows of data from table sales and two from table prices that you expect to get in the third table ? And show us that expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do as simple as this:

```
CREATE TABLE revenue as
select s.product, s.`date`, s.amount, p.price * s.amount
from sales s
join prices p on s.product = p.product;
```

This last line:

```
join prices p on s.product = p.product;
```

is what I have assumed the join condition might be...

[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f62d913abf37cbdd1075c32308345bdf)

Answer (score 0):

First of all avoid using `implicit joins` because they are deprecated since a while and using reserved words like [date] if needed you have to enclose column names if they have spaces / special characters or include SQL keywords:

```
INSERT INTO revenue (product , [date], amount , revenue)
SELECT s.product, s.[date], s.amount,p.price*s.amount 
FROM sales AS s
INNER JOIN prices AS p ON (join condition)
```

You may need `CAST()` for `prices.price*sales.amount` part if you encounter any conversion issues.